# AppBundler does not bundle JRE 8 Preview correctly

Tags: java, macos, ant, java-8

I try to bundle my Java Application as a Mac .app "file" using ant and the AppBundler from projects from [Java.net](http://appbundler.java.net) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler).

It works fine with the JDK/JRE 7u25, but unfortunately Java 7 on Mac OS X has a bug about special characters in file names. This issue is addressed in Java 8. I am aware that the current Java 8 is only a preview at the moment and things are likley to not work perfectly fine.

Actually the ant task which creates the bundle runs without error, but when I try to start the programm, it just won't run.

So I opened a terminal and started the JavaAppLauncher directly:

```
% ./JavaAppLauncher 
Error: dl failure on line 670
Error: failed /Users/krickl/git/PowerFolder-Pro/dists/PowerFolder_Generic/PowerFolder.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre//lib/server/libjvm.dylib, because dlopen(/Users/krickl/git/PowerFolder-Pro/dists/PowerFolder_Generic/PowerFolder.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre//lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/krickl/git/PowerFolder-Pro/dists/PowerFolder_Generic/PowerFolder.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre//lib/server/libjvm.dylib: truncated fat file.  file length=4194304, but needed slice goes to 10978336
```

Does anybody know, what this message is about and what I am doing wrong here? Or is this an issue regarding the preview version of Java 8 I use?

Comment: Please finish your question.

Comment: You can get Java 7 to work fine with special characters in file names by setting the environment variable LC_CTYPE=UTF-8

Comment: @greg-449 Actually I did this already. With the AppBundler that I took from BitBucket, the LC_CTYPE is set to UTF-8 in the Info.plist file. This did change the handling of special characters in the UI, but not with the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today Oracle released the Developer Preview of Java 8. With this release I managed to bundle the Mac App.